# Join rows with closest column value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to join two tables where T1Col1=T2Col1 and T1Col2=T2Col2 and find the closest match of T1Col3 to T2Col3. One is to one row only.

Table1

```
 Col1 |Col2  |Col3
 123  |ABC   |20170731000022
 123  |ABC   |20170731000019
 234  |DEF   |20170731110001
 234  |DEF   |20170731110003
```

Table2

```
 Col1 |Col2  |Col3
 123  |ABC   |20170731000020
 234  |DEF   |20170731110000
 234  |DEF   |20170731110002
```

Output

```
 T1Col1  |T1Col2  |T1Col3           |T2Col1  |T2Col2  |T2Col3
 123     |ABC     |20170731000022   |        |        |
 123     |ABC     |20170731000019   |123     |ABC     |20170731000020
 234     |DEF     |20170731110001   |234     |DEF     |20170731110000
 234     |DEF     |20170731110003   |234     |DEF     |20170731110002
```

Comment: Your suggested join is full of problems.  For example `20170731110001` has an exact match in both tables, but you don't want to join this record together.  I would suggest that you clean up your data such that you don't need to do fuzzy joins like this.  Even if implemented, the logic could substantially change the result set even with the introduction of a single row of data.  Unstable results aren't a good thing.

Comment: Sorry. I just updated my data. Its supposed to be 20170731110000.

Comment: Also, the absence of a (visible) primary key in both tables makes the join difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query ,it works in SQL server .Hope this helps with your problem .Basically I am finding the absolute difference between col3 in tab1 and col3 in tab2 and then ranking them and picking the least value .Her eif multiple rows have the same ranking (the difference being same ) then we pick one of them.If you want only the positive column you need to remove the abs

```
select * from 
(
   select t.*,
   row_number() over(partition by t1col1,t1col2 order by diff asc) as rn 
   from
     (
        select tab1.col1 as t1col1,tab1.col2 t1col2,tab1.col3 
        t1col3,tab2.col1 t2col1,tab2.col2 t2col2,tab2.col3 
        t2col3,abs(tab1.col3-tab2.col3) as diff
        from tab1 join tab2 
        on tab1.col1=tab2.col1
        and tab1.col2=tab2.col2
     )t
    )f where rn=1
```